# Replacing twitter usernames (@...) with "USERNAME" - how to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reduce features of my twitter corpus. For that reason I intend to substitute usernames with an equivalence class token. The usernames are characterized by starting with an @. I tried using re.sub(), but it does not work as intended. It replaces names in the sentences, but not at the beginning of a sentence. What is wrong?

```
#usernames (e.g. @max) are replaced with An equivalence class token 

import re
with open('outfilename2.csv',"r", encoding="utf-8") as oldfile1, open('outfilename3.csv', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as newfile1:
    for line in oldfile1:
        line=re.sub(r"(\s)@\w+", r" USERNAME", line)
        newfile1.write(line)
newfile1.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is wrong for what you're claiming to want to do:

```
line=re.sub(r"\B@\w+", "USERNAME", line)
```

If you want to match `@anything_anywhere` where `@` is preceded by a non-boundary character and replace it with `USERNAME`.

Answer (score -1):

Line = Line.split("{")[1].split("}")[0]
That may help

Comment: the user names in the tweets are not in parenthesises, but they are normal text that start with an @.

Comment: example tweet: "I went shopping @sarah."
goal: "I went shopping USERNAME."

Comment: Username.upper() makes it uppercase